# How do I force wix to update a file before manipulating it on an upgrade

Tags: xml, wix, upgrade

I have a wix installer that will install an XML file and then modify it.  Installation works great.  Today, I needed to add a couple of nodes to this XML file.  So I modified the original file and then added some additional instructions to wix to assign these items values.

Well, I get an error every time saying that it cannot find the node.  I look and see what file it has in the directory and it still has the older file that did not have the node.  How can I tell it to replace the XML file first and then modify it?  I don't want to use "CreateElement" because I don't know how to not create an element if it exists already (haven't tried it, so maybe it'd work).  Besides, I want my XML file to be the definition of the configuration.

Here's a sample of my XML:

```
      <Component Id="MyProgExeConfigComponent" Guid="*">
    <File
      Id="MyProgExeConfig"
      Name="MyProg.exe.config"
      DiskId="1"
      Source="../Published/MyProg/MyProg.exe.config"
      PatchWholeFile="yes"
      KeyPath="yes"/>
    <util:XmlFile
      Id="MyProgExeConfigUser"
      Action="setValue"
      Permanent="yes"
      File="[INSTALLLOCATION]\MyProg.exe.config"
      ElementPath="/configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key='UserName'[\]]"
      Name="value"
      Value="[USER]"/>
    <util:XmlFile
      Id="MyProgExeConfigPassword"
      Action="setValue"
      Permanent="yes"
      File="[INSTALLLOCATION]\MyProg.exe.config"
      ElementPath="/configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key='Password'[\]]"
      Name="value"
      Value="[PASSWORD]" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows Installer is probably not overwriting the file because you have INSTALLMODE=omus and the XML's create and modification dates are different.

Is the XML file the key file of it's own component?   If so, try using the File@DefaultVersion attribute to trick Windows Installer into thinking the new file has a version #  ( we call this 'Version Lying" when googling )   and therefore trumps the non-versioned file.   Your file will be overwritten and then your XML updates can be applied from there.

Comment: Sweet!  That worked.  Thanks again, Chris.  Now do I need to increment this version every time I make a change to the XML file?

Comment: No.  I usually just set the version to upper bound ( 65535.65535.65535.65535 ) or similar and you are fine.  The real deployed file will never have a version number.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some further options: [Forcing an upgrade of a file that is modified during its initial installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432251/forcing-an-upgrade-of-a-file-that-is-modified-during-its-initial-installation). Personally I like the companion file approach best.