# .exe with same version but different size not upgrading while majot upgrade in wix

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I am doing majot upgrade in wix. I have one service.exe whose size changed in MR from 7k to 21k. still it is not replacing while executing msi. Other files got replaced what will be the problem.

I will explore a little more. I am doing major upgrade. I have installed msi having version 1.1.0.1. Now major upgrade build is 1.1.1.0. The files having extension other than .exe are overwriting in major upgrade. there is one file service.exe whose version is same in both msi so major upgrade skipping that file from being overwritten. What should do so that service.exe should upgrade.

The version of service.exe is 1.0.0.0 is both build however its size changed.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. What have you tried and what didn't work? How about updating that version number if you're doing a major upgrade?

Comment: I will explore a little more. I am doing major upgrade. 
I have installed msi having version 1.1.0.1. 
Now major upgrade build is 1.1.1.0. 
The files having extension other than .exe are overwriting in major upgrade. there is one file service.exe whose version is same in both msi so major upgrade skipping that file from being overwritten.
What should do so that service.exe should upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Hi got the solution refered [Forcing an upgrade of a file that is modified during its initial installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432251/forcing-an-upgrade-of-a-file-that-is-modified-during-its-initial-installation)

I have set REINSTALLMODE = amus like property Id=REINSTALLMODE value=amus

thanks...